# H20 Hadoop Start up

Tags: hadoop, h2o

I am trying to set up H20 on Hadoop ,so we have a HDP2.5 Hadoop cluster and i have downloaded and unzipped : h2o-3.18.0.8-hdp2.5 on my edgenode  .

I ran :
 hadoop jar h2odriver.jar -nodes 1 -mapperXmx 6g -output /user//h20test

I see that its getting launched ,but the ui seems to binding to 127.0.0.1 and when i go to browser as expected its not working.Can someone please help

Sample Log from above command :

Job name 'H2O_84301' submitted
JobTracker job ID is 'job_1523015956637_0262'
For YARN users, logs command is 'yarn logs -applicationId application_1523015956637_0262'
Waiting for H2O cluster to come up...
H2O node 127.0.0.1:54321 requested flatfile
Sending flatfiles to nodes...
    [Sending flatfile to node 127.0.0.1:54321]
H2O node 127.0.0.1:54321 reports H2O cluster size 1 [leader is 127.0.0.1:54321]
H2O cluster (1 nodes) is up
(Note: Use the -disown option to exit the driver after cluster formation)

Open H2O Flow in your web browser: http://127.0.0.1:54321

(Press Ctrl-C to kill the cluster)
Blocking until the H2O cluster shuts down...

Comment: Look at the -network option

Comment: @TomKraljevic:  i added -network <hostnameofedgenode> ,but it failed with "ERROR: network invalid:  <ip>"

Comment: It's mapping to localhost on the edge node... You're trying to open localhost on your own computer and expecting a UI to appear?

Comment: @cricket_007 : No ,I know this will not work and hence i am asking how to make it map to actual server ip so that i can use the Flow UI on my local browser.

Comment: I'm not sure what options are available to remap the network address, but one option would be a reverse proxy using nginx or Apache http server

Answer (score 0):

Use the -network option.

Here is the help output for the -network option:

```
-network <IPv4network1Specification>[,<IPv4network2Specification> ...]
      The IP address discovery code will bind to the first interface
      that matches one of the networks in the comma-separated list.
      Use instead of -ip when a broad range of addresses is legal.
      (Example network specification: '10.1.2.0/24' allows 256 legal
      possibilities.)
```

Provide the proper specification for the interface that you want the Flow Web UI to bind to.

For example:

```
hadoop jar h2odriver.jar -nodes 1 -mapperXmx 6g -network 10.1.2.0/24 -output h2otmp/junk001
```